# How to check dynamic if conditions

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, if-statement, conditional-statements

I need to check dynamic if condition through my application. this is sample code of my application.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int newValue = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter NO");
        int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (10 < x && x < 20)
        {
            newValue = 1;
        }
        else if (20 < x && x < 30)
        {
            newValue = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            newValue = 3;
        }
    }
}
```

But I need to check those conditions (`20 < x && x < 30`) dynamically. How can I do this? I need to get those conditions through my database. which means I need to store those conditions in my database table. but there also have a problem. If database have those two conditions `20 < x && x < 30` and `10 < x && x < 40`, when **x = 25** both conditions will be through. So I also need to prevent store those invalid, confused conditions in a database. please give me a solution to do this. How I check dynamic if conditions through application & how to store conditions properly in my database (SQL Server)

Thank you.

**Update**: suppose in future I need to add additional conditions(also need to change current conditions ) to the system, ex: `else if (40< x && x < 60)`. if I hard code as belove code, I'm unable to do that. therefor I plan to store condition in db, but I haven't any idea to do that.

Comment: can you provide an example of the values you're storing in your database?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to store in the database? I have read this several times and it makes less sense each time I read it.

Comment: I would advise against this approach (which is essentially executing dynamic C# code).   Can you explain a bit about the problem you are trying to solve?  I have a feeling there may be a simpler solution than this.

Comment: @SeanLange sir my problem is if I need to add an additional condition to the system, I'm unable to do that if I hardcode as belove. therefor I think to store conditions in the db. I have no idea to that, I need solution to it.

Comment: @jtate sir currenty I'm not do that,coz I havent idea to do it

Comment: Here is the problem, it is completely unclear what you want to do. I get that you want an answer but you first need to provide a complete question.

Comment: @SeanLange I updated my question sir,is it now clear

Comment: Do you always have range conditions like that? If so then the problem isn't storing the conditions it is the whole design. You should be storing this type of logic in the database. But not at mathematical equations, as data. No offense but the whole approach here is just the wrong way to do this.

Comment: @SeanLange yes sir, I always have range conditions like this. Ok then how to do this. please give me the best solution to do this.

Comment: It sounds to me like you could just store the bounds as Min, Max along with a target map value. You would essentially end up with a collection of objects with 3 values: Min, Max, Value. So your selection would end up being MyCollection.Where(x => x.Min < value && x.Max >= value).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value), instead of having a bunch of if-statements. How you build that collection - whether from a file, some DB, or by other means, is entirely up to you and is tangential to your core problem here. I would personally start by prototyping against just an in-memory collection of objects.

Comment: @Zoinks Thank you sir, I'm really stack on this. so please help me to solve this. please give me a best answer to solve this. please

Comment: Despite the fact that SO is NOT a "give me a solution" type of place I cobbled together something to at least you get you started to think about data.

Comment: What's this got to do with `SQL Server`???

Comment: @Eric I plan to store those conditons in DB

Comment: @Gamma But in this question, there's not a single SQL code.

Answer (score 3):

Not entirely sure what you want to accomplish but here is what I would do to store your conditions in sql. First we need a table and some data (This should be the example you posted).

```
create table MyConditions
(
    ConditionID int identity primary key clustered
    , MinValue int
    , MaxValue int
    , Result int
)

insert MyConditions
(
    MinValue
    , MaxValue
    , Result
) values
(10, 20, 1)
, (20, 30, 2)
, (null, 10, 3)
, (30, null, 3)
```

And then you just need a simple query to return the correct mapped value for any input value. Something like this should work. This is really just a guess at what you are trying to do but it does work for the sample posted. You could tweak the ranges and adjust < or <= etc to suit the logic you need to handle.

```
declare @x int = 251 --this represents the user input value

select *
from MyConditions
where @x > isnull(MinValue, @x - 1)
    AND @x <= isnull(MaxValue, @x)
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir, but suppose if client adds `(10, 20, 1)` and `(5, 25, 7)` then it makes confused. because when **@x  = 15** both conditions will be true. so I need to prevent add invalid conditions adding | if user need to add  `(5, 25, 7)` this he must need to delete `(10, 20, 1)` this before adding this condtion `(5, 25, 7)`

Comment: Again I am shooting in the dark here. To be honest something about the whole process seems very off to me but I have no idea what you are trying to solve. I got you started, YOU have to put in some effort here.

Comment: I'm really sorry sir, I'm new to C#,  I'm developing a simple web application for my university project. in my application admin panel admin add those condition. however your answer really awesome(now admin can insert those values to db). but now problem, I need to add some validation to prevent insert invalid conditions.such as `(10, 20, 1)` `(5, 25, 7)`. because both will be true when the value = **10-20**

Comment: You could add an integer column called Priority, give each rule a priority and process the rules in Priority order until you get a successful match.

Comment: Or use top 1 order by Priority desc. That would be better than looping when you don't need to. But honestly for a school project just get it done.

Comment: @SeanLange I'm not clear it sir, can you please edit your answer, sir? please give me code example to do it

Comment: @user1443098 please give me code example to do it sir

Comment: This is not a free consulting service where you ask for code and other write it for you. Especially since you are in school YOU need to put in some effort here. Remember it is you that will have to do this in the real world. That means it is YOU that need to understand how this stuff works.